# Need Help on Error with Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

I want to import a Navigation Drawer in my App. I code it in Fragments, but my app crashes on start and I get the following error:

> Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference

Code:

```
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

public class NavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout NavDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;


    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, NavDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        NavDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);

        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        NavDrawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I can't see a bug in my code...

//Edit for better info...

Ok, i have do it, but now come a new error...

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

but i dont know who code is it...

Here the XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation_drawer"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

//edit ok i have make it... and the error

> Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(android.support.design.widget.NavigationView$OnNavigationItemSelectedListener)' on a null object reference

come already...

```js
public class NavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout NavDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;
  
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);

        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, NavDrawer,
                toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); 
            }
        };

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        NavDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        NavigationView nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);

        NavDrawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 

        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                NavDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        toggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
 
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                fragmentClass = Home.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_artikel:
                fragmentClass = Artikel.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_facebook:
                fragmentClass = Facebook.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_instagram:
                fragmentClass = Instagram.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_twitter:
                fragmentClass = Twitter.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_manage:
                fragmentClass = Settings.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                fragmentClass = Share.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_send:
                fragmentClass = Send.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = Home.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        NavDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }

}
```

This is Completted Navigation java....

Comment: Can you post relevant XMLs? E.g `activity_navigation_drawer`...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is that you are not returning anything from your `setupDrawerContent()`. So when you assign `ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = setupDrawerToggle;` `toggle` will be a null value. When you then try to `addDrawerListener` you are getting a NullPointerException for trying to set a drawer listener that is null.

Below is an example from [Google's Creating a Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) for properly setting up your drawer listener.

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
```

Comment: Where do you see the `addDrawerListener()` method in the Exception message?

Comment: i have add it in onCreate.. NavDrawer.addDrawerListener(toogle);